# change text on button and enabled status after click button(asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I use ASP.NET to develop.
Here, I want the thing is that once I click button A (the text on the button A is "Start"), then the text on the button A will change to "processing...please wait" and button A will become not clickable. Then execute the stored procedure(the duration of stored procedure is 1 minute). After the stored procedure finishes, the text on the button A will change to "Start" and button A will become clickable.

I tried that before stored procedure, I added these codes:

```
ButtonA.Text = "processing...please wait";
ButtonA.Enabled = false;
```

And after stored procedure, I added these codes:

```
ButtonA.Text = "Start";
ButtonA.Enabled = true;
```

But the outcome is the text on the button A is not changed and button A is still clickable during the stored procedure is executing.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Then I edit my aspx file to be below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server"/>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlHelloWorld" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonA" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonA_Click" Text="Start" />
         </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonA" EventName="Click"/> 
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But the text of button still remains the same and the button is still clickable.

Comment: That won't work. The UI is updated only once after the page is done loading and send to the client. It does not update in between. If you want to change the Button texts like that you are gonna have to use Ajax.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that by using Ajax? I am new to Ajax. Thank you

Comment: You can achieve that using Ajax.For doing so, put the components inside `UpdatePanel` control. In your case you will put `Buttons` inside the UpdatePanel. So whenever you will click `ButtonA`, your request will be processed and you will get response back from the server.Please note only controls inside `UpdatePanel` will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by using Ajax. Using Ajax you can do partial page refresh.
Put `ButtonA` inside the `UpdatePanel`, and it should work as expected.

You can refer below sample code for reference. 

*webpage.aspx code*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlHelloWorld" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonA" OnClick="btnHelloWorld_Click" Text="Update label!" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*c# code*

```
protected void btnHelloWorld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Before Procedure call
        ButtonA.Text = "processing...please wait";
        ButtonA.Enabled = false;

        //Call Procedure
        procedure ....
       //After Prodedure call
       ButtonA.Text = "Start";
       ButtonA.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Hope that helps, thanks.

Comment: I added ScriptManager and UpdatePanel part, then it turns out nothing happens even I click the button. Do you know what's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I referenced your solution and solution of other people, but still can't work. I already updated my code.